# Dealing with multiple input parameters using wrapper class

Tags: api, oop, interface, constructor

As a sort of continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351165/dealing-with-lots-of-input-parameters-lots-of-outputs), I have the following newbie question:

What difference is there in building a wrapper class that expects lots of inputs parameters and inputting those parameters directly into the final constructor?

Don't get me wrong, I think the multiple input parameter thing is pretty ugly, and I'm trying to get around it since just like the poster of that question, I need to deal with a Calculator-like class that requires a lot of parameters. But what I don't understand is what would a wrapper class for input parameters solve, since I also need to build the input class--and that's just as ugly as the other alternative.

To summarize, I don't think this:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int param1, int param2, int param3... int paramN)
{
    this->param1 = param1;
    this->param2 = param2;
    this->param3 = param3;
    ...
    this->paramN = paramN;
}
```

...is much different from this:

```
Result MyClass::myInterface(MyInputClass input)
{
    //perform calculations
}

MyInputClass::MyInputClass(int param1, int param2, int param3... int paramN)
{
    this->param1 = param1;
    this->param2 = param2;
    this->param3 = param3;
    ...
    this->paramN = paramN;
}
```

And, of course, I am trying to avoid setters as much as possible.

Am I missing something here? I'd love to have some insight on this, since I'm still a rather newbie programmer.

Comment: As a sidenote, why are you trying to avoid setters in your parameter class?

Comment: Because I don't really like the idea of setters. It's been argued to death, but I really think setters go completely against the idea of having a clean interface for an object, separating data by public and private fields.

That doesn't mean they shouldn't be used. It just means I think they ought to be used sparingly, and only when there really isn't much choice.

Comment: If the arguments are only passed in the constructor and there isn't a change to them later from another object avoiding setters is perfectly fine and a very good choice

Answer (score 3):

The biggest benefits are:

- Insulation from changes. You can add
  new properties to the parameter class
  and not have to change the class that
  uses it or any of its callers.
- Code reduction when you're chaining
  methods. If `MyClass` needs to pass
  its parameters around, `MyInputClass`
  eliminates a bunch of code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some of the reasons, one would like to use a parameter class:

- Reusability: You can save the parameters in a variable and reuse them, maybe in another method.
- Separation of concerns: Parameter handling, say to verify which parameters are active, which are in their correct ranges, etc., is performed in the parameter class; your calculation method only knows how to calculate, so in the future you know where is each and no logic is mixed.
- You can add a new value and impact minimally in your calcultor method.
- Maybe your calculator method can be applied to two different set of parameters, say on an integer and on a double.  It is more readable/mantainable/faster to write the calculation logic just once and change the parameter object.

Some classes do not need to initialize every single field at the constructor.  Sometimes setters are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

All the other points are completely valid and sound.  Here's a little reinforcement from some authoritative text:

Code Complete suggests that you *limit the number of parameters of any routine to seven*, as "seven is the magic number for people's comprehension."  It then goes on to suggest that passing more than seven parameters increases coupling with the calling scope and that you should use a structured variable (ala `MyInputClass`) instead.